# Unable to modify database table in sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was working on sql server management studio and i have connected it with visual studio 2019. While working i deleted one column from my table and the table has relationship with other tables. Now, when i tried to insert the column again it brings message that says'cannot insert value null into column password insert failed and the statement has been terminated'

Comment: If you're adding the column and you define it as `NOT NULL` you **must** provide a default constraint and tell SQL Server (not SSMS, that's just an IDE) to populate the column with `WITH VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add new NOT NULL column to existing table, you have to define Default value for the new column in the SSMS, as given below:

[image: Default value for new column]